# AWS::S3::Errors::AccessDenied. Cannot save to S3 with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-s3, paperclip

I am attempting to connect Amazon S3 to my site so to store user avatars. I expect users to be able to add an avatar to their profiles, but it seems that I am denied access. I've looked at and tried several solutions with no success:

[Ruby Amazon S3 Access Denied when listing buckets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11147961/ruby-amazon-s3-access-denied-when-listing-buckets)

[How to solve “Access Denied” with Heroku + Paperclip + S3 + ROR](http://rexstjohn.com/how-to-solve-access-denied-with-heroku-paperclip-s3-ror/)

[Uploading to S3 With Paperclip](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3)

**Error message:**

> AWS::S3::Errors::AccessDenied: Access Denied File "/app/app/controllers/profiles_controller.rb", line 13 in create

**Full Trace:**

```
2016-02-03T23:30:12.826846+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (1.3ms)
2016-02-03T23:30:12.830420+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 9ms (Views: 6.1ms | ActiveRecord: 1.2ms)
2016-02-03T23:30:12.821127+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
2016-02-03T23:30:12.830151+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.9ms)
2016-02-03T23:30:12.824076+00:00 app[web.1]:   Plan Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "plans".* FROM "plans"  WHERE "plans"."name" = 'mentee' LIMIT 1
2016-02-03T23:31:23.614411+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by ProfilesController#create as HTML
2016-02-03T23:31:23.618346+00:00 app[web.1]:   User Load (1.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 32  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
2016-02-03T23:31:23.621171+00:00 app[web.1]:   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "32"]]
2016-02-03T23:31:23.642828+00:00 app[web.1]: Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/tmp/907d62dfd370e834d14b2f9e69569f8f20160203-3-oy7ex6.jpg[0]' 2>/dev/null
2016-02-03T23:31:23.731583+00:00 app[web.1]: Command :: convert '/tmp/907d62dfd370e834d14b2f9e69569f8f20160203-3-oy7ex6.jpg[0]' -auto-orient -resize "300x300>" '/tmp/907d62dfd370e834d14b2f9e69569f8f20160203-3-oy7ex620160203-3-zkzzqj'
2016-02-03T23:31:23.610892+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/users/32/profile" for 108.80.140.163 at 2016-02-03 23:31:23 +0000
2016-02-03T23:31:23.615000+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"ArxGVYON7jf+nRR9HfMcpHWxSgk4uHIw7ELCnDaJhvc=", "profile"=>{"not_available"=>"0", "first_name"=>"Kim", "last_name"=>"Crayton", "avatar"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fe496024c48 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20160203-3-1nmybbz>, @original_filename="Kim Crayton.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"profile[avatar]\"; filename=\"Kim Crayton.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">, "contact_email"=>"kimmcrayton@gmail.com", "city"=>"Atlanta", "state"=>"GA", "country"=>"USA", "coding_languages"=>"HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Python", "bio"=>"I was an educator, writer, and researcher in another life who decided to dive into the coding end of the pool. I've learned the basics on my own and like most who want to swim in the Olympics, I need a good coach to get me to the next level.", "mentoring_needs"=>"To be able to level up my skill set to become employed as a Jr. Developer"}, "commit"=>"Update Profile", "user_id"=>"32"}
2016-02-03T23:31:23.620344+00:00 app[web.1]:   User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 32]]
2016-02-03T23:31:23.629345+00:00 app[web.1]: Command :: file -b --mime '/tmp/7ad9d08462a928e43510aef94b436bb820160203-3-1p8wtua.jpg'
2016-02-03T23:31:23.717450+00:00 app[web.1]: Command :: identify -format %m '/tmp/907d62dfd370e834d14b2f9e69569f8f20160203-3-oy7ex6.jpg[0]'
2016-02-03T23:31:24.346558+00:00 app[web.1]: Command :: file -b --mime '/tmp/907d62dfd370e834d14b2f9e69569f8f20160203-3-oy7ex620160203-3-zkzzqj'
2016-02-03T23:31:24.468671+00:00 app[web.1]: Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/tmp/907d62dfd370e834d14b2f9e69569f8f20160203-3-oy7ex6.jpg[0]' 2>/dev/null
2016-02-03T23:31:25.276211+00:00 app[web.1]: Command :: identify -format %m '/tmp/907d62dfd370e834d14b2f9e69569f8f20160203-3-oy7ex6.jpg[0]'
2016-02-03T23:31:25.356070+00:00 app[web.1]: Command :: convert '/tmp/907d62dfd370e834d14b2f9e69569f8f20160203-3-oy7ex6.jpg[0]' -auto-orient -resize "100x100>" '/tmp/907d62dfd370e834d14b2f9e69569f8f20160203-3-oy7ex620160203-3-6j3feu'
2016-02-03T23:31:25.933442+00:00 app[web.1]: Command :: file -b --mime '/tmp/907d62dfd370e834d14b2f9e69569f8f20160203-3-oy7ex620160203-3-6j3feu'
2016-02-03T23:31:25.968535+00:00 app[web.1]:    (1.8ms)  BEGIN
2016-02-03T23:31:26.011723+00:00 app[web.1]:   SQL (1.9ms)  INSERT INTO "profiles" ("avatar_content_type", "avatar_file_name", "avatar_file_size", "avatar_updated_at", "bio", "city", "coding_languages", "contact_email", "country", "created_at", "first_name", "last_name", "mentoring_needs", "state", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12, $13, $14, $15, $16) RETURNING "id"  [["avatar_content_type", "image/jpeg"], ["avatar_file_name", "Kim_Crayton.jpg"], ["avatar_file_size", 588778], ["avatar_updated_at", "2016-02-03 23:31:23.627122"], ["bio", "I was an educator, writer, and researcher in another life who decided to dive into the coding end of the pool. I've learned the basics on my own and like most who want to swim in the Olympics, I need a good coach to get me to the next level."], ["city", "Atlanta"], ["coding_languages", "HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Python"], ["contact_email", "kimmcrayton@gmail.com"], ["country", "USA"], ["created_at", "2016-02-03 23:31:26.002769"], ["first_name", "Kim"], ["last_name", "Crayton"], ["mentoring_needs", "To be able to level up my skill set to become employed as a Jr. Developer"], ["state", "GA"], ["updated_at", "2016-02-03 23:31:26.002769"], ["user_id", 32]]
2016-02-03T23:31:25.965320+00:00 app[web.1]:   Profile Load (8.5ms)  SELECT  "profiles".* FROM "profiles"  WHERE "profiles"."user_id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 32]]
2016-02-03T23:31:26.012791+00:00 app[web.1]: [paperclip] saving /profiles/avatars/000/000/024/original/Kim_Crayton.jpg
2016-02-03T23:31:25.972587+00:00 app[web.1]: Command :: file -b --mime '/tmp/7ad9d08462a928e43510aef94b436bb820160203-3-1fkobfh.jpg'
2016-02-03T23:31:26.192049+00:00 app[web.1]: [AWS S3 403 0.176059 0 retries] put_object(:acl=>:public_read,:bucket_name=>"BUCKET_NAME_VALUE",:content_length=>588778,:content_type=>"image/jpeg",:data=>Paperclip::UploadedFileAdapter: Kim Crayton.jpg,:key=>"profiles/avatars/000/000/024/original/Kim_Crayton.jpg") AWS::S3::Errors::AccessDenied Access Denied
2016-02-03T23:31:26.192052+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-02-03T23:31:26.199059+00:00 app[web.1]:    (5.4ms)  ROLLBACK
2016-02-03T23:31:26.239693+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2625ms
2016-02-03T23:31:26.278651+00:00 app[web.1]: [Rollbar] Scheduling payload
2016-02-03T23:31:26.278749+00:00 app[web.1]: [Rollbar] Sending payload
2016-02-03T23:31:26.255527+00:00 app[web.1]: [Rollbar] Reporting exception: Access Denied
2016-02-03T23:31:26.565131+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/users/32/profile" host=www.jrdevmentoring.com request_id=39b4d6a4-de82-4746-bba2-15326511c36c fwd="108.80.140.163" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=5691ms status=500 bytes=1754
2016-02-03T23:31:26.556786+00:00 app[web.1]: [Rollbar] Success
2016-02-03T23:31:26.556867+00:00 app[web.1]: [Rollbar] Details: https://rollbar.com/instance/uuid?uuid=e2c97cca-326f-4501-a1ac-dabcedc8d047 (only available if report was successful)
2016-02-03T23:31:26.556955+00:00 app[web.1]: [Rollbar] Exception uuid saved in env: e2c97cca-326f-4501-a1ac-dabcedc8d047
2016-02-03T23:31:26.562072+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-02-03T23:31:26.562074+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/profiles_controller.rb:13:in `create'
2016-02-03T23:31:26.562075+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-02-03T23:31:26.562074+00:00 app[web.1]: AWS::S3::Errors::AccessDenied (Access Denied):
2016-02-03T23:31:26.562075+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-02-03T23:32:23.939135+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/users/32/profile/new" host=www.jrdevmentoring.com request_id=a926abfc-e512-42cc-bcf0-b49f0e660051 fwd="108.80.140.163" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=22ms status=304 bytes=844
2016-02-03T23:32:23.921568+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"user_id"=>"32"}
2016-02-03T23:32:23.921563+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by ProfilesController#new as HTML
2016-02-03T23:32:23.924214+00:00 app[web.1]:   User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 32  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
2016-02-03T23:32:23.926869+00:00 app[web.1]:   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "32"]]
2016-02-03T23:32:23.934672+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered profiles/_form.html.erb (5.2ms)
2016-02-03T23:32:23.934795+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered profiles/new.html.erb within layouts/mentee_layout (5.5ms)
2016-02-03T23:32:23.935958+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.4ms)
2016-02-03T23:32:23.919293+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/users/32/profile/new" for 108.80.140.163 at 2016-02-03 23:32:23 +0000
2016-02-03T23:32:23.926294+00:00 app[web.1]:   User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 32]]
2016-02-03T23:32:23.936324+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 15ms (Views: 8.2ms | ActiveRecord: 2.5ms)
2016-02-03T23:32:23.928924+00:00 app[web.1]:   Plan Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "plans".* FROM "plans"  WHERE "plans"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 30]]
2016-02-03T23:32:24.067025+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-ccf1b63ef283bc859fc20d775228d578.js" host=www.jrdevmentoring.com request_id=fd39d73a-d506-4b69-ac11-042db1ca8cee fwd="108.80.140.163" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=16ms status=304 bytes=133
2016-02-03T23:32:24.051947+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-9750215382cdb39b0d4756e6b205dd25.css" host=www.jrdevmentoring.com request_id=7f1972d5-75f3-469c-9672-2d149981a9b9 fwd="108.80.140.163" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=8ms status=304 bytes=133
2016-02-03T23:32:28.231345+00:00 app[web.1]:   User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 32]]
2016-02-03T23:32:28.222520+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/users/32/profile" for 108.80.140.163 at 2016-02-03 23:32:28 +0000
2016-02-03T23:32:28.367338+00:00 app[web.1]: Command :: identify -format %m '/tmp/907d62dfd370e834d14b2f9e69569f8f20160203-3-150cqxf.jpg[0]'
2016-02-03T23:32:28.240793+00:00 app[web.1]: Command :: file -b --mime '/tmp/7ad9d08462a928e43510aef94b436bb820160203-3-133toy1.jpg'
2016-02-03T23:32:28.225432+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by ProfilesController#create as HTML
2016-02-03T23:32:28.225555+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"ArxGVYON7jf+nRR9HfMcpHWxSgk4uHIw7ELCnDaJhvc=", "profile"=>{"not_available"=>"0", "first_name"=>"Kim", "last_name"=>"Crayton", "avatar"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fe496024c48 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20160203-3-spce1k>, @original_filename="Kim Crayton.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"profile[avatar]\"; filename=\"Kim Crayton.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">, "contact_email"=>"kimmcrayton@gmail.com", "city"=>"Atlanta", "state"=>"GA", "country"=>"USA", "coding_languages"=>"HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Python", "bio"=>"I was an educator, writer, and researcher in another life who decided to dive into the coding end of the pool. I've learned the basics on my own and like most who want to swim in the Olympics, I need a good coach to get me to the next level.", "mentoring_needs"=>"To be able to level up my skill set to become employed as a Jr. Developer"}, "commit"=>"Update Profile", "user_id"=>"32"}
2016-02-03T23:32:28.229747+00:00 app[web.1]:   User Load (1.7ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 32  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
2016-02-03T23:32:28.232006+00:00 app[web.1]:   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "32"]]
2016-02-03T23:32:28.411553+00:00 app[web.1]: Command :: convert '/tmp/907d62dfd370e834d14b2f9e69569f8f20160203-3-150cqxf.jpg[0]' -auto-orient -resize "300x300>" '/tmp/907d62dfd370e834d14b2f9e69569f8f20160203-3-150cqxf20160203-3-bep14i'
2016-02-03T23:32:28.254571+00:00 app[web.1]: Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/tmp/907d62dfd370e834d14b2f9e69569f8f20160203-3-150cqxf.jpg[0]' 2>/dev/null
2016-02-03T23:32:29.005396+00:00 app[web.1]: Command :: file -b --mime '/tmp/907d62dfd370e834d14b2f9e69569f8f20160203-3-150cqxf20160203-3-bep14i'
2016-02-03T23:32:29.215235+00:00 app[web.1]: Command :: identify -format %m '/tmp/907d62dfd370e834d14b2f9e69569f8f20160203-3-150cqxf.jpg[0]'
2016-02-03T23:32:29.042851+00:00 app[web.1]: Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/tmp/907d62dfd370e834d14b2f9e69569f8f20160203-3-150cqxf.jpg[0]' 2>/dev/null
2016-02-03T23:32:29.254140+00:00 app[web.1]: Command :: convert '/tmp/907d62dfd370e834d14b2f9e69569f8f20160203-3-150cqxf.jpg[0]' -auto-orient -resize "100x100>" '/tmp/907d62dfd370e834d14b2f9e69569f8f20160203-3-150cqxf20160203-3-18abmic'
2016-02-03T23:32:29.899670+00:00 app[web.1]: Command :: file -b --mime '/tmp/907d62dfd370e834d14b2f9e69569f8f20160203-3-150cqxf20160203-3-18abmic'
2016-02-03T23:32:29.934163+00:00 app[web.1]:   SQL (1.0ms)  INSERT INTO "profiles" ("avatar_content_type", "avatar_file_name", "avatar_file_size", "avatar_updated_at", "bio", "city", "coding_languages", "contact_email", "country", "created_at", "first_name", "last_name", "mentoring_needs", "state", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12, $13, $14, $15, $16) RETURNING "id"  [["avatar_content_type", "image/jpeg"], ["avatar_file_name", "Kim_Crayton.jpg"], ["avatar_file_size", 588778], ["avatar_updated_at", "2016-02-03 23:32:28.238610"], ["bio", "I was an educator, writer, and researcher in another life who decided to dive into the coding end of the pool. I've learned the basics on my own and like most who want to swim in the Olympics, I need a good coach to get me to the next level."], ["city", "Atlanta"], ["coding_languages", "HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Python"], ["contact_email", "kimmcrayton@gmail.com"], ["country", "USA"], ["created_at", "2016-02-03 23:32:29.931498"], ["first_name", "Kim"], ["last_name", "Crayton"], ["mentoring_needs", "To be able to level up my skill set to become employed as a Jr. Developer"], ["state", "GA"], ["updated_at", "2016-02-03 23:32:29.931498"], ["user_id", 32]]
2016-02-03T23:32:29.983370+00:00 app[web.1]: [AWS S3 403 0.044695 0 retries] put_object(:acl=>:public_read,:bucket_name=>"BUCKET_NAME_VALUE",:content_length=>588778,:content_type=>"image/jpeg",:data=>Paperclip::UploadedFileAdapter: Kim Crayton.jpg,:key=>"profiles/avatars/000/000/025/original/Kim_Crayton.jpg") AWS::S3::Errors::AccessDenied Access Denied
2016-02-03T23:32:29.989703+00:00 app[web.1]: [Rollbar] Reporting exception: Access Denied
2016-02-03T23:32:29.918738+00:00 app[web.1]:    (3.9ms)  BEGIN
2016-02-03T23:32:29.985462+00:00 app[web.1]:    (1.0ms)  ROLLBACK
2016-02-03T23:32:29.913438+00:00 app[web.1]:   Profile Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "profiles".* FROM "profiles"  WHERE "profiles"."user_id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 32]]
2016-02-03T23:32:29.983374+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-02-03T23:32:29.935107+00:00 app[web.1]: [paperclip] saving /profiles/avatars/000/000/025/original/Kim_Crayton.jpg
2016-02-03T23:32:29.920674+00:00 app[web.1]: Command :: file -b --mime '/tmp/7ad9d08462a928e43510aef94b436bb820160203-3-9amf8x.jpg'
2016-02-03T23:32:29.986839+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1761ms
2016-02-03T23:32:30.038337+00:00 app[web.1]: [Rollbar] Sending payload
2016-02-03T23:32:30.035794+00:00 app[web.1]: [Rollbar] Scheduling payload
2016-02-03T23:32:30.297265+00:00 app[web.1]: [Rollbar] Success
2016-02-03T23:32:30.298549+00:00 app[web.1]: [Rollbar] Exception uuid saved in env: fe95e497-18b6-4711-8141-94789670b5ed
2016-02-03T23:32:30.312149+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/profiles_controller.rb:13:in `create'
2016-02-03T23:32:30.312147+00:00 app[web.1]: AWS::S3::Errors::AccessDenied (Access Denied):
2016-02-03T23:32:30.298468+00:00 app[web.1]: [Rollbar] Details: https://rollbar.com/instance/uuid?uuid=fe95e497-18b6-4711-8141-94789670b5ed (only available if report was successful)
2016-02-03T23:32:30.312144+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-02-03T23:32:30.312149+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-02-03T23:32:30.312150+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-02-03T23:32:30.317622+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/users/32/profile" host=www.jrdevmentoring.com request_id=6930043a-4007-4c13-9a38-0cac82aac0b6 fwd="108.80.140.163" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4641ms status=500 bytes=1754
2016-02-03T23:41:43.818611+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=www.jrdevmentoring.com request_id=05a31e30-d8d1-465e-9a0d-4a545668949a fwd="107.206.188.61" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=58ms status=200 bytes=3069
2016-02-03T23:41:43.800534+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 107.206.188.61 at 2016-02-03 23:41:43 +0000
2016-02-03T23:41:43.808750+00:00 app[web.1]:   Plan Load (1.4ms)  SELECT  "plans".* FROM "plans"  WHERE "plans"."name" = 'mentor' LIMIT 1
2016-02-03T23:41:43.815175+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 9ms (Views: 4.7ms | ActiveRecord: 2.0ms)
2016-02-03T23:41:43.812975+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (1.0ms)
2016-02-03T23:41:43.805782+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
2016-02-03T23:41:43.810095+00:00 app[web.1]:   Plan Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "plans".* FROM "plans"  WHERE "plans"."name" = 'mentee' LIMIT 1
2016-02-03T23:41:43.814699+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.5ms)
2016-02-03T23:41:44.007715+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-ccf1b63ef283bc859fc20d775228d578.js" host=www.jrdevmentoring.com request_id=8a323d54-7eb3-4f09-bbb2-cc1f245654bf fwd="107.206.188.61" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=20ms status=200 bytes=142105
2016-02-03T23:41:44.113132+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-9750215382cdb39b0d4756e6b205dd25.css" host=www.jrdevmentoring.com request_id=198cd717-23b5-413d-8903-9d5f944884e0 fwd="107.206.188.61" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=23ms status=200 bytes=114067
```

**profiles_controller.rb**

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :only_current_user

  def new
    # form where a user can fill out their own profile.
    @user = User.find( params[:user_id] )
    @profile = Profile.new
  end
  def create
    @user = User.find( params[:user_id] )
    @profile = @user.build_profile(profile_params)
    if @profile.save
      flash[:success] = "Profile Updated!"
      redirect_to user_path( @user )
    else
        flash[:danger] = "An error occurred and your profile has not been updated. You must complete all form fields."
        render action: :new
    end
  end
  def edit
    @user = User.find( params[:user_id] )
    @profile = @user.profile
  end
  def update
    @user = User.find( params[:user_id] )
    @profile = @user.profile
    if @profile.update_attributes(profile_params)
     flash[:success] = "Profile Updated!"
      redirect_to user_path( params[:user_id] )
    else
     render action: :edit
    end
  end
  private
    def profile_params
      params.require(:profile).permit(:not_available, :first_name, :last_name, :avatar, :contact_email, :city, :state, :country, :coding_languages, :bio, :mentoring_needs)
    end
    def only_current_user
      @user = User.find( params[:user_id] )
      redirect_to(root_url) unless @user == current_user
    end
end
```

production.rb

```
 config.paperclip_defaults = {
    :storage => :s3,
    :s3_credentials => {
      :bucket => ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
      :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
      :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
    }
  }
```

profile.rb

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  validates :first_name, presence: true
  validates :last_name, presence: true
  validates :contact_email, presence: true
  validates :bio, presence: true
  validates :mentoring_needs, presence: true
  validates_length_of :coding_languages,  minimum: 1, maximum: 500
  validates_length_of :bio,  minimum: 1, maximum: 1000
  validates_length_of :mentoring_needs,  minimum: 1, maximum: 500

  has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

Comment: Which line is line 13? Where is the S3 connection made? Apparently you're using Heroku because it's in your tags, but are your environment variables set? Please provide more information about your situation

Comment: It won't let me edit because someone else already has. Line 13:  if @profile.save

Comment: I guess you are that someone

Comment: yes, I edited to improve formatting and the question title. You can make additional edits though

Comment: When I tried to add the line it told me that someone had made substantial changes and that I couldn't edit. Anyway, I'm new and I'm sure that my questioning style is low so please explain "but are your environment variable set?" I've been trying to get this to work for hours

Comment: You need to set your AWS credentials as config variables in heroku (basically environment variables). You can check if they are set with `heroku config`; if they are not set, you can add them with `heroku config:set S3_BUCKET_NAME=something AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=whatever AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=something_secret`. More info with `heroku config --help`.

Comment: thanks @taglia...that worked :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35190087/awss3errorsaccessdenied-cannot-save-to-s3-with-rails#comment58099232_35190087) by user [taglia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/676366/taglia)

> You need to set your AWS credentials as config variables in heroku (basically environment variables). You can check if they are set with heroku config; if they are not set, you can add them with `heroku config:set S3_BUCKET_NAME=something AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=whatever AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=something_secret`. More info with heroku config --help

Comment: You can accept your own answer since it has been 48 hours since the question was asked. I have included a citation for the comment you quoted here. In order to make this slightly more informative, perhaps you could also edit in what worked by using this approach so that those who find this post in the future will have a better chance at solving their problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem after AWS changed their policy to require an IAM user.  I created the new IAM user and received new credentials for the IAM user, and after updating my app with the new credentials, I received this same error.  I fixed it by going back to AWS, Services, IAM User, and creating a permission for the user to have AdministratorAccess.